# error with heroku that workds on 000webhost

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, heroku, pdo

Okay so I am new to using heroku and postgres but I am having trouble here and I can't figure how to fix it.

So in my index page there is an option for users to subscribe to a newsletter. When they enter their email the site will check that what's been entered is valid and if the email has already subscribed, if everything is fine the email will be added to the table in the database.

The html and script for it is as follows:

```
 <div id="subscribe">
                <h2>Want to keep up-to-date with what is going on?</h2>
                <p>Subscribe to our newsletter!</p>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email here..."><br /><br />
                <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                <div id="result" style="margin-top: 50px;"></div> 
            </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#email');
        $('#email').keypress(function(event) {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            if (keyCode == 13) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'subscribe.php',
                    data: {email: email},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#result').hide();
                        $('#result').html(data);
                        $('#result').fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            };
        });
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'subscribe.php',
                data: {email: email},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').hide();
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    $('#result').fadeIn();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My subscripe.php file is:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/configure.php');    

$message  = "<html><body>";



$message .= "<table width='100%' bgcolor='#e0e0e0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";

$message .= "<tr><td>";

$message .= "<table align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='max-width:650px; background-color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'>";

$message .= "<thead>
  <tr height='80'>
  <th colspan='4' style='background-color:#f5f5f5; border-bottom:solid 1px #bdbdbd; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size: 27px;' >Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter. Make sure to check your junk box in case we unfortunately end up there </th>
  </tr>
             </thead>";

$message .= "<tbody>



              </label>
       </td>
       </tr>

        <tr height='20'>
       <td colspan='4' align='center' style='background-color:#f5f5f5;'>



       </td>
       </tr>


              </tbody>";

$message .= "</table>";

$message .= "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";

$message .= "</body></html>";

$email = $_POST['email'];

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'mail/Exception.php';
require 'mail/PHPMailer.php';
require 'mail/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $emails = $_POST['email'];
    if (filter_var($emails, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $query = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `subscribe` WHERE `email` = ?" );
        $query->bindValue( 1, $email );
        $query->execute();

        if( $query->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query
        echo "You have already subscribed";
        }
    else {
            try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $dbconn->prepare('INSERT INTO subscribe (email) VALUES (:email)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':email' => $email

                ));


            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
     echo "Thank you for subscribing";  

try {


    $mail->setFrom('*******', 'Newsletter');
   $mail->addAddress('*******', '***');
   $mail->Subject = 'Newsletter';
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Username = '*******';
   $mail->Password = '******';
   $mail->Port = 587;

       if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'])) {
        $mail->Subject = 'Subscription';
        //keeps it simple
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        // a simple message body
        $mail->Body = $_POST['email']. " has subscribed to the newsletter";

        //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            //The reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo

            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Thanks for subscribing!.';
            //header("Refresh:3; url=index.html#contact");
        //  echo "Your message was successfully sent";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }



            $mail->ClearAddresses();
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->Body = $message;
            $mail->send();


   /* Enable SMTP debug output. */
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

  // $mail->send();


}


catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}

        } 

 } else {
        echo "Please enter a valid email...";
    }

    }

//}



 ?>
```

So when I enter something just like "lewis" into the email field it gives the correct output of "Please enter a valid email" but as soon as I put in an actual email address I get this error in the console:

```
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 POST https://sheltered-reef-10750.herokuapp.com/subscribe.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ (index):147
dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
```

When I look at the heroku logs I am getting:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`
2020-05-03T14:22:03.664784+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT `email` FROM `subscribe` WHERE `email` = $1
2020-05-03T14:22:03.664898+00:00 app[web.1]: ^ in /app/subscribe.php:74
2020-05-03T14:22:03.664959+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2020-05-03T14:22:03.665054+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/subscribe.php(74): PDOStatement->execute()
2020-05-03T14:22:03.665085+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 {main}
2020-05-03T14:22:03.665185+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/subscribe.php on line 74
2020-05-03T14:22:03.665730+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.37.232.57 - - [03/May/2020:14:22:03 +0000] "POST /subscribe.php HTTP/1.1" 500 373
```

So my question is why am I getting that console error? Is there something that needs to be added to composer.json file for heroku?

And what is wrong with this bit of code:

```
    $query = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `subscribe` WHERE `email` = ?" );
    $query->bindValue( 1, $email );
    $query->execute();
```

I have used this elsewhere and not had any issues

Comment: You used `$emails` for `$emails = $_POST['email'];` and then `$email` in `$query->bindValue( 1, $email );`.

Comment: ah yeah, you're right thank you, dumb mistake there. Changed it and that errors goes away now but get a smtp could not authenticate? Does heroku allow phpmailer to be used?

Comment: You're welcome. Besides that, I don't know what it could be. If what you used works on one server but not another. makes sure that the paths are correct and all files exist too. The error states an 500 error, being a server error. Try adding error reporting for the PHP and use error checking on the PDO. Look at your HTML source also. That could reveal things. Plus, make Heroku doesn't allow certains files, it's been too long since I've used their services.

Comment: the console error stopped once that emails mistake was fixed and in order to allow phpmailer to be used I had to go to DisplayUnlockCaptcha and now it works fine